# difference between #if defined(WIN32) and #ifdef(WIN32)

Tags: c

I am compiling my program that will run on linux gcc 4.4.1 C99.

I was just putting my `#defines` in to separate the code that will be compiled on either windows or linux. However, I got this error.

```
error: macro names must be identifiers.
```

Using this code

```
#ifdef(WIN32)
/* Do windows stuff */
#elif(UNIX)
/* Do linux stuff */
#endif
```

However, when I changed to this the error was fixed:

```
#if defined(WIN32)
/* Do windows stuff */
#elif(UNIX)
/* Do linux stuff */
#endif
```

Why did I get that error and why the `#defines` are different?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

If you use #ifdef syntax, remove the parenthesis.

The difference between the two is that `#ifdef` can only use a single condition,
while `#if defined(NAME)` can do compound conditionals.

For example in your case:

```
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(UNIX)
/* Do windows stuff */
#elif defined(UNIX) && !defined(WIN32)
/* Do linux stuff */
#else
/* Error, both can't be defined or undefined same time */
#endif
```

Comment: yeah, but you could also cascade #ifdef UNIX with #ifndef WIN32, and get the same flexibility (not as readable, I agree)

Comment: @jpinto3912 But that gets even hairier with `||`

Comment: If only they had just gone with `#if defined(NAME)` from the start and avoided creating an `#ifdef` statement.

Comment: Sourceforge has a [good reference](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) on pre-defined compiler macros.

Answer (score 77):

```
#ifdef FOO
```

and

```
#if defined(FOO)
```

are the same,

but to do several things at once, you can use defined, like

```
#if defined(FOO) || defined(BAR)
```

Answer (score 36):

`#ifdef` checks whether a macro by that name has been defined, `#if` evaluates the expression and checks for a true value

```
#define FOO 1
#define BAR 0

#ifdef FOO
#ifdef BAR
/* this will be compiled */
#endif
#endif

#if BAR
/* this won't */
#endif

#if FOO || BAR
/* this will */
#endif
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asks for difference between `#if defined` and `#ifdef`.

Comment: This is the best explanation of how #if FOO and #if defined(FOO) can behave differently.

Comment: A useful answer since it shows the subtle difference between `#ifdef` and `#if`

Answer (score 1):

With C23, you can use `#elifdef` and `#elifndef`:

```
#ifdef WIN32
/* Do windows stuff */
#elifdef UNIX
/* Do linux stuff */
#endif
```