# Using multiple terms in a #ifdef

Tags: c

Is there a way for me to do the following in C?

```
#ifdef MACRO_1 && MACRO_2
...
#endif
```

Writing this directly causes a compilation error.

Comment: @PaulR I would argue that while the answer linked answers both questions, the question linked is not the same

Comment: I think it's close enough, but I'll check for other duplicates which might be closer. Feel free to vote to re-open though - that's how the system works, after all...

Answer (score 4):

[This SO answer on - Is #if defined MACRO equivalent to #ifdef MACRO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290019/is-if-defined-macro-equivalent-to-ifdef-macro) explains it wonderfully.

Instead of using `#ifdef`, use `#if defined(...)`. Since `defined(...)` will evaluate to a 0 or 1, it'll behave as a normal `#if`

Code would look like the following:

```
#if defined(MACRO_1) && defined(MACRO_2)
...
#endif
```

Comment: @PaulR thanks! didn't see that