# What is the difference between #ifdef VALUE vs #if defined (VALUE)

Tags: c++, c, macros, directive, preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 0
int main()
{
#ifdef MAX
printf("MAX defined");
#endif
#if defined (MAX)
printf("MAX is defined");
#endif
return 0;
}
```

Both the `#ifdef` and `#if defined` give the same effect then what is the difference between them? I have not seen the disassembly code of these directives if you have seen then kindly try to explain that as well.

Comment: functionally, they're equivalent, however, `#if defined()` allows logical operators like `#if defined(A) || defined(B)`, while `#ifdef A || B` is invalid syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714255/1632887

Comment: Since these are preprocessor directives, there will be no code generated for them. They don't exist at all when the compiler starts compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is historical. Originally there was only `#ifdef`. The newer syntax is more flexible and allows combining tests with logical conditions, but in the simple form you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: Hello can you give an example?

Comment: Made up example: `#if defined WINDOWS && defined _DEBUG`